# Django file uploader throwing error "cannot pickle '_io.BufferedRandom' object" while uploading more thank 2.5mb of image using celery

Tags: python, django, serialization, celery, pickle

i am trying to upload image files in Django, i am sending the upload task into the task queue using celery, but when I upload image files larger than 2.5mb it crashes with this error  `cannot pickle '_io.BufferedRandom' object` i have added some settings options to Django but that does not work.

## celery application settings

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 90005000
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_TLS')
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

is there any way I can solve this issue, a reminder when am uploading the image files using Django alone, it works regardless the size, so the issue is from celery not been able to work with file larger than 2.5MB

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` variable in `settings.py`.

E.g.,

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024 # 10 Mb limit
```

If required, you need to configure the Nginx server with the same limit as well.